# Bootstrap full-width div inside container

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, containers

on my website, generally all divs inside the "container-fluid"-div should be centered width a max-size, because it should be easy for the end-user to use in CMS-System.

But in special cases, i would like to create a div INSIDE the container, which has full-size, see here: http://www.bootply.com/ouSn0oOBCJ

My problem: The horizontal scrollbars.
Even on ipad, the viewport zooms out to the whole page.

What can i do? thanks in advance

Comment: you can use "container" for your div.

Comment: for which div, the outer div oder the inner div? I want the normal text to be centered width a max. size. But only a special div should have full-width.

Comment: you can use col-md-12 for full width

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap uses padding for its container-fluid divs. 15px for right and left.
If you mention that a children has 100% width, then it will be **100% + 30px**!

What you can try in css:

```
width: calc(100% - 30px);
```

Comment: my problem is, that the "margin-left:-2000px; and margin-right:-2000px;" produce the scrollbars, but i used this, to get the background-color in full width.